# Hide parent div class if child div class does not have content when there are multiple parent divs with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider where some of the images in the slider can have an optional photo- credit containing text or link in a popper.   I would like to iterate over all of the popper instances and if all of the p tags in the .photo-credit p class are empty, then hide only that instance of the parent popper.  I've tried to piece together a solution from some other posts, but have not been able to get it to work.  The code I have does not hide a popper if all p tags are empty for that popper.  I'm a JavaScript newbie and would appreciate any help.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<!--Required Root Element-->
<div class="slider">
    <!--Required List Element-->
    <div class="slider-list">
        <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="slider-image-container"><img class="slider-image" src="http://www.someurl.com/Images/Homepage Images/Slider/image1.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="slider-content-container">
                <h1>B LIne: The Place to Be</h1>
                <div class="learn-more"><a href="http://www.someurl.com">Learn More</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popper">
                <img data-toggle="popover" class="photo-credit-icon" src="http://www.someurl.com/icon-photography.svg" alt="photo credit" />
            </div>
            <div class="photo-credit hide">
                <p><p><a href="http://www.someurl.com">A photo credit</a>.</p></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div><div class="slider-item">
            <div class="slider-image-container"><img class="slider-image" src="http://www.someurl.com/Images/Homepage Images/Slider/anotherimage.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="slider-content-container">
                <h1>July 4th: You missed it!</h1>
                <div class="learn-more"><a href="http://www.someurl.com">Learn More</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popper">
                <img data-toggle="popover" class="photo-credit-icon" src="http://www.someurl.com/icon-photography.svg" alt="photo credit" />
            </div>
            <div class="photo-credit hide">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div><div class="slider-item">
            <div class="slider-image-container"><img class="slider-image" src="http://www.someurl.com/Images/Homepage Images/Slider/anotherimage.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="slider-content-container">
                <h1>Festival coming Aug. 31st!</h1>
                <div class="learn-more"><a href="http://www.someurl.com">Learn More</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popper">
                <img data-toggle="popover" class="photo-credit-icon" src="http://www.someurl.com/icon-photography.svg" alt="photo credit" />
            </div>
            <div class="photo-credit hide">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="slider-control-prev"><img src="http://www.someurl.com/images/icons/icon-chevron-left-slider.svg"></a>
<a href="#" class="slider-control-next"><img src="http://www.someurl.com/images/icons/icon-chevron-right-slider.svg"></a>

<p class="slider-pagination"></p>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
     $('.popper').each(function () {
            //var $thisPopper = $(this);
            var hasContent = 0;
            $('.photo-credit p').each(function () {
                if($(this).html().length > 0) {
                  hasContent++;
                }
            });
            if(hasContent > 0){
                //$thisPopper.hide();
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right direction. However a couple mistakes in your javascript.
You tried to target all the div with "popper" class. However, the div with "popper" and "photo-credit" are on the same level. Why not targeting their parent div instead?

Try this code. It's been tested ([Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bysawsj1/2/))

```
$('.slider-item').each(function () {
        var thisSilerItem = $(this);
        var hasContent = 0;
        thisSilerItem.find('.photo-credit p').each(function () {
            if($(this).html().length > 0) {
              hasContent++;
            }
        });
        if(hasContent <= 0){
            thisSilerItem.find('.popper').hide();
        }
    });
```

**Edit**:
Bonus:
If your page has a large amount of sliders, this jquery solution will cause some UX issues ("jumpy" div on/after page load)

Try a CSS only solution.

When you render your DOM elements. Add a class to "popper" div if the content of "photo-credit" is empty.

```
<div class="popper hide">
// img
</div>
```

Then in your CSS, add

```
.popper.hide { display: none; }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully gather what you want to do, but if I understand correctly...

```
$('.popper').each(function () { 

  var photoCredit = $(this).find(".photo-credit p")

    if ( $(photoCredit).is(':empty') ){
      $(this).hide();
    }

});
```

It's worth pointing out that CSS4 developers are working on a 'has' selector but as of July 2017 there is no support for any browser just yet.

It is expected to work in the following manner:

```
.popper:has(> p:empty) { display: none }
```

I hope this helps... :)

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work as expected, but appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be much help...

If you create a fiddle or a Codepen with the previous posted HTML and some CSS I can certainly look at it for you...just post the link here

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code.

```
        $.each($('.popper'), function (index, popper) {
            var isEmptry = true;
            $.each($(popper).next('.photo-credit').children(), function (index, ptag) {
                if ($.trim($(ptag).html()) != '')
                    isEmptry = false;
            });
            if (isEmptry)
                $(popper).hide();
        });
```

Working code

```js
$.each($('.popper'), function (index, popper) {
    var isEmptry = true;
    $.each($(popper).next('.photo-credit').children(), function (index, ptag) {
        if ($.trim($(ptag).html()) != '')
            isEmptry = false;
    });
    if (isEmptry)
        $(popper).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <!--Required Root Element-->
    <div class="slider">
        <!--Required List Element-->
        <div class="slider-list">
            <div class="slider-item">
                <div class="slider-image-container">
                    <img class="slider-image" src="http://www.someurl.com/Images/Homepage Images/Slider/image1.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content-container">
                    <h1>B LIne: The Place to Be</h1>
                    <div class="learn-more"><a href="http://www.someurl.com">Learn More</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="popper">
                    <img data-toggle="popover" class="photo-credit-icon" src="http://www.someurl.com/icon-photography.svg" alt="photo credit" />
                </div>
                <div class="photo-credit hide">
                    <p>
                        <p><a href="http://www.someurl.com">A photo credit</a>.</p>
                    </p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
                <div class="slider-image-container">
                    <img class="slider-image" src="http://www.someurl.com/Images/Homepage Images/Slider/anotherimage.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content-container">
                    <h1>July 4th: You missed it!</h1>
                    <div class="learn-more"><a href="http://www.someurl.com">Learn More</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="popper">
                    <img data-toggle="popover" class="photo-credit-icon" src="http://www.someurl.com/icon-photography.svg" alt="photo credit" />
                </div>
                <div class="photo-credit hide">
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
                <div class="slider-image-container">
                    <img class="slider-image" src="http://www.someurl.com/Images/Homepage Images/Slider/anotherimage.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content-container">
                    <h1>Festival coming Aug. 31st!</h1>
                    <div class="learn-more"><a href="http://www.someurl.com">Learn More</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="popper">
                    <img data-toggle="popover" class="photo-credit-icon" src="http://www.someurl.com/icon-photography.svg" alt="photo credit" />
                </div>
                <div class="photo-credit hide">
                    <p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="slider-control-prev">
        <img src="http://www.someurl.com/images/icons/icon-chevron-left-slider.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" class="slider-control-next">
        <img src="http://www.someurl.com/images/icons/icon-chevron-right-slider.svg"></a>

    <p class="slider-pagination"></p>

</div>
```